# How to search a word from the .txt file that has been included in the project in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, search, nsstring

I have included a .txt file in my project and i have to find a keyword from that file by entering the keyword in the search bar. Help me with the piece of code for searching the keyword that is present in the file.

Comment: Do you just want to verify that keyword entered in search bar is present in the .txt file or what do you want to achieve after search text is entered?

Comment: How big is the file? Does it have a set format? Can you change the format? Are you doing partial matches? @VishalVaja

Answer (score 3):

Try that

```
//Get the contents of the file
NSString *contentString = [NSString stringWithContentOfFile:<i>path/to/your/file.txt</i> encoding:<i>textEncoding<i> error:<i>&error</i>];

if (!error) {
    NSRange range = [contentString rangeOfString:<i>yourKeyword</i>];

    if (theRange.location != NSNotFound)
       //do whatever you want
}
```

NB : this will work as long as your text file is not "too big". If you have to work with bigger files, take a look at NSInputStream to only parse chunks of the file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)searchWord:(NSString *)wordToBeSearched{
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wordFile"
                                             ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:NULL];

NSString *delimiter = @"\n";
NSArray *items = [content componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
NSString *character = @" ";
BOOL isContain = NO;
for (NSString *wordToBeSearched in items) {
isContain = ([string rangeOfString:wordToBeSearched].location != NSNotFound);
}
return isContain; 

}
```

You can go here for more [details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI)